# ActiveRecord summing columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to get the sum of multiple columns on a row of a table inside of a map, but sum only works on a model selection like this:

```
columns = 'col1 + col2 + col3'

Model.all.map do |model|
  Model.where(:id => model.id).sum(columns)
end
```

I'm trying to do this, so I don't have to access the database again and obviously it does not work:

```
columns = 'col1 + col2 + col3'

Model.all.map do |model|
  model.sum(columns)
end
```

Any ideas or tricks on how to do this? Keep in mind, `columns` must be used as the values of `columns` will change based on several criteria.

Comment: So you really want to `model.col1 + model.col2 + model.col3` for each `model` but the actual expression you want to use is in the `columns` string?

Comment: Yes, but I believe Stefan's solution is probably best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SQL queries outside the database. However, if I understand your question correctly, something like this should work:

```
columns = 'col1 + col2 + col3'

Model.select("*, #{columns} AS my_sum").map do |model|
  model.my_sum  # the calculated sum
end
```

Make sure to properly escape your custom SQL queries.